# Newsletter Subscribe magento2

Tags: magento2, newsletter

I am using below code for newsletter subscription.

```
$email = 'test@email.com';
$subscriberFactory = $objectManager- >get('\Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory');
$subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
```

It is working fine, how can i add first name and last name as well as type also? Is it possible that way?

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is no field for saving the name (first name and last name) in the **newsletter_subscriber** table.

If you want to save these values, first you need to **create a custom module** and add the fields to hold first name and last name in the table.

Next, to save these values, you can either override **`Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber`** or write a plugin for that.

I hope you know how to create a plugin.

Below is the sample code for the plugin:

```
<?php
namespace Stack\Newsletters\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class Subscriber {
    protected $request;
    public function __construct(Http $request){
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function aroundSubscribe($subject, \Closure $proceed, $email) {

        if ($this->request->isPost() && $this->request->getPost('fname')) { 

            $fname = $this->request->getPost('fname');
            $lname = $this->request->getPost('lname');

            $subject->setFname($fname);
            $subject->setLname($lname);
            $result = $proceed($email);

            try {
                $subject->save();
            }catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: I have custom form with fname , lname and email fields, subscription is working fine with above code i mentioned in question, how can i add fname and lname is my issue, I think plugin is not required for me

Comment: Please check updated answer now. By your way, it is not possible to add firstname and lastname. You need to modify model function.

Comment: I think plugin is not required for me? Why i need to use plugin for it? I have created custom forms in several places like homepage, category page, pdp page etc, any of the form submits i need to subscribe with that data

Comment: If i create plugin, how it takes my form to submit? I have 3 forms in different pages

Comment: have you got my point? @mohit

Comment: What is $subject in your code?

Comment: The parameter $subject is the original object or class you are writing a plugin for.

Comment: I tired your code you have sent me via email, setLname and setFname are not working for me